# MySQL SELECT FROM table Whose Name is in Another Table

Tags: mysql

I have a partitioned log database that increments the name every month so that the database doesn't get too large and hinder performance. The names of all partitioned tables are stored in another table and the new partition is inserted into this table when it is created.

I can get the latest partition name fairly easily:

`SELECT partition_name FROM table_partitions ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1`

I get one row with a `partition_name` of `1_2021_11`

How can I get the value of this partition name into another SELECT statement? Essentially, replacing `newestPartition` in this SELECT statement:

`SELECT * FROM newestPartition`

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL with `PREPARE`.

Answer (score 0):

That is only possible with dynamic sql

Like

> ```
> CREATE TABLe table_partitions (partition_name varchar(10),start_date date)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table_partitions VALUES('abc', NOW())
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE abc(id int)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT partition_name INTO @partition FROM table_partitions ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @partition, '');
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> | id |
> | -: |
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33304713f53b03db9f2897aae0020679)*

Answer (score 0):

First, `select` your query into a variable

```
SELECT concat('select * from ', partition_name, ';') into bar FROM table_partitions ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Then prepare a statement:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @bar;
```

Finally execute it

```
EXECUTE stmt;
```